# Notify SignalR Clients of IIS restart/shut down

Tags: c#, .net, iis, signalr

I have a SignalR Server (*A Web App*) and a Client (*A Console App*).

I want my Client(s) to be notified whenever IIS of my Server gets restarted/shut down or Server gets restarted/shut downs simply.

Is it possible?

Comment: you mean restarting the entire IIS server or just the worker process of your app?

Comment: As a trigger for a scheduled task, or a [windows service](http://forums.iis.net/t/1180869.aspx?IIS+Windows+Service) ?

Comment: @AliHasan, I believe both would be same but i'm more keep to know about worker process restart.

Comment: Shouldn't you post what you've tried first??

Comment: @enki.dev, added that as answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this

```
var connection = new HubConnection(hubUrl);
if (configureConnection != null)
    configureConnection(connection);

var proxy = connection.CreateHubProxy("EventAggregatorProxyHub");
connection.Reconnected += reconnected;
```

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/blob/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Client.DotNet/Bootstrap/Factories/HubProxyFactory.cs#L17

Other events are

- Reconnecting - Fired when it tries to reconnect after connection closed
- Closed - Fired when connection is lost

**Update:**

`Closed` will be called when reconnecting have failed (When IIS have been down for a longer period than accepted by Reconnect timeout).

This means that you should reconnect from the Close event using `connection.Start()` when it fails the Closed event will be called again and can retry again with `connection.Start()`.

Here is an example using my code, it will survive both that IIS is down when app starts and that it goes down while running

```
public class HubProxyFactory : IHubProxyFactory
{
    public IHubProxy Create(string hubUrl, Action<IHubConnection> configureConnection, Action<IHubProxy> onStarted, Action reconnected, Action<Exception> faulted, Action connected)
    {
        var connection = new HubConnection(hubUrl);
        if (configureConnection != null)
            configureConnection(connection);

        var proxy = connection.CreateHubProxy("EventAggregatorProxyHub");
        connection.Reconnected += reconnected;
        connection.Error += faulted;

        var isConnected = false;

        Action start = () =>
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Start().Wait();
                    if(isConnected)
                        reconnected();
                    else
                    {
                        isConnected = true;
                        onStarted(proxy);
                        connected();
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    faulted(ex);
                }
            });
        };

        connection.Closed += start;

        start();

        return proxy;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe that Reconnected would work only when/if iss boots up after restarting. I want to notify when it goes off. Was not mentioned in question sorry. Will update.

Comment: Closed seems to be promising, might work. Thanks I'll try that out. Will accept if that works :)

Comment: no it didn't work. Reconnected or Closed doesn't get fire when I stops my ISS while Client is running. However Closed does get fired IF my Client starts and IIS is already down. Thanks for the help though, upvoted.

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong, I just tried running my app, and type iisreset or cycle app pool. Both triggered Reconnected on my .NET client

Comment: I was starting/stopping from IIS manager's Manage Website panel, on right side. Is it different than what you are doing?

Comment: Nope, thats equal to iisreset from cmd (But more correct to real world is to recycle app pool)

Comment: My client is a console app (for testing only, i'll be creating windows service for production) which keeps alive due to a timer's tick thread. Does that makes any difference?

Comment: Thanks for the update but your phrase "When IIS have been down for a longer period..." doesn't fit my needs. Actually as per requirements that I have I cannot afford to wait I need something instant.

Comment: Well long in this case is a couple of seconds, if the connection goes upp in matter of seconds Reconnected event will fire. If not the Closed event will, then you need to reconnect manually. code above will safly reconnect once IIS is up again

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have as of right now (*very much of an Indian jubaad though*) is to try reconnecting to SignalR server every time in a certain time interval.

```
HubConnection _connection = new HubConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.UserLoginDataSource);
IHubProxy _hub;

void TryConnectingDataSource()
{
 try
 {

   _connection.Stop();
   _connection.Dispose();

   _connection = new HubConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.UserLoginDataSource);
   _connection.StateChanged += connection_StateChanged;
   _hub = _connection.CreateHubProxy("myHub");
   _connection.Start().Wait();

   if (_connection.State == ConnectionState.Connected)
   {
      _hub.On("myHubCallback", new Action<Dictionary<string, Entities.Permissions.UserTypes>>(GetUserLoginList));
      _hub.Invoke("myHubMethod");
   }
 }
 catch (Exception x)
 {
   EventLogger.LogError(x);
 }
}
```

If I'll be caught by Catch that would mean something is wrong with Connection most likely ISS is down.